# Unable to mount a windows share drive

Tags: files, mount

I have to access some files present in a windows share drive from a linux machine which is running centos. I am able to do this from a Mac machine using the command

```
sudo mount_smbfs //username@path/to/file /Users/username/foo
```

I am not sure if mounting is the way to go in the linux machine or even on Mac. So how can I access it? Finally my objective is to write a shell script that will fetch the files automatically from the windows share drive to the linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mount your windows share under centos:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //host/path/to/share /Users/username/foo -ousername=<username>,password=<password>
```

if you want to mount at boot time add to /etc/fstab the line

```
//host/path/to/share  /Users/username/foo cifs username=<username>,password=<password> 0 0
```